# Why does \if with \fancypagestyle only work inside header and footer declarations?

Tags: conditionals, fancyhdr

I am writing a package where the first page has a custom header and footer made by `fancyhdr` while the remaining the pages have a different page style. However, I am curious as to the reason why this code works:

```
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
...
\fancypagestyle{custom}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \chead{
    \ifnum\thepage=1%
      First
    \else%
      Not first
    \fi
  }
  \cfoot{
    \ifnum\thepage=1%
      First
    \else%
      Not first
    \fi
  }
}
```

Yet this code fails and outputs the first page header and footer for all pages:

```
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
...
\fancypagestyle{custom}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \ifnum\thepage=1
    \chead{First}
    \cfoot{First}
  \else
    \chead{Not first}
    \cfoot{Not first}
  \fi
}
```

I do not have a very good grasp of programming LaTeX, but I am interested in why LaTeX would make a distinction between the two. Why does it happen that these two code samples produce different documents? Is it a result of fancyhdr, the LaTeX `\if`, or a mixture of both?

Comment: It should be `\ifnum\value{page}=1` (no `%` at the end of the line). You're generally using `%` where it shouldn't be used, and not using it where it should.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is the difference between `\value{page}` and `\thepage`?

Comment: `\value{page}` is the “abstract” value of the counter, `\thepage` its representation (that could be in Roman numbers or alphabetic). Probably it makes no difference in your case, but using `\thepage` is conceptually wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the second form is testing the page number at the point that you make the declaration. the code in the first form is testing the page number each time you execute the page head, on every page.